# Multiple pivots in U-SQL to output multiple columns?

Tags: pivot, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Is it possible to perform multiple pivots in U-SQL without doing a UNION? Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT Email
FROM @somedata
PIVOT (
     MIN(EventTimestamp) FOR EventType IN ("A" AS FirstATime, "B" AS FirstBTime)
),
PIVOT (
     MAX(EventTimestamp) FOR EventType IN ("A" AS LastATime, "B" AS LastBTime)
)
GROUP BY Email
```

The resulting columns should be:

```
Email, FirstATime, FirstBTime, LastATime, LastBTime
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compose `PIVOT` expressions. Please note that `PIVOT` is a rowset expression. Thus it will take a rowset on its left hand side argument.

I think you would like to apply two different aggregations over the same data with the `PIVOT`s though. In that case, I think you will need to do it in two `SELECT`s and then do an [`OUTER UNION ALL BY NAME ON (Email)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/union-and-outer-union-expression-u-sql) to merge the rows.

Comment: OUTER UNION almost works, but it doesn't combine the left and right into single rows. I end up with 

`EmailValue, FirstATimeValue, FirstBTimeValue, NULL, NULL` 
and
`EmailValue, NULL, NULL, LastATimeValue, LastBTimeValue` 

These then need to be combined again with an outer select, which I was trying to avoid. Is there a UNION that will combine these for me automatically?

Comment: What about using `OUTER UNION ALL BY NAME ON (EmailValue)` or `OUTER UNION ALL BY NAME ON (*)`? I updated my answer.

Comment: That doesn't get me what I want either. I ended up just creating two resultsets and then joining them together.

Comment: Thanks... I am glad you found a working solution. As a tip: it helps us to answer if you can provide a simple input and output example. That way we can test the proposed solution and see if we miss an aspect.